# Php method chaining not working, returning an PDO error

Tags: php

I am trying to chaing several methods, in this case I am trying to create a way to build a sql query(with PDO) but its not working.

I am trying to build (end result, for now first the select & all part)

```
$products->select('id, name')->where(['category'=>'car'])->all()
```

Combined code

```
class Query {

    private $table = 'products';
    private $stmt;
    private $db;


    public function __construct()
    {
        //demo, this works
        $this->db = new PDO();
    }

    //Function where is not neede for now

    public function select()
    {
        // not working
        $table = $this->table;
        $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $this->stmt->execute();
        return $this->stmt;

        // this will work
        // $results = $products->select();
        $table = $this->table;
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $query->execute();
    
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
    }

    public function all()
    {
       $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

$products = new \App\Models\Query;

// Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::all() 
$products->select()->all();
```

Comment: Where is the method `where` defined?

Comment: Nowhere, as I said that for a next time

Comment: Your `select` function is not returning `self`. It returns `$this->stmt` or an array from `fetchAll`. To be able to use method chaining you need to return `self`